# Can a Devise model be associated with another devise model and how to Oauth them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, associations, omniauth

I'm struggling to design an architecture in which a Devise User (with omniauth authentications) can also maintain an Artist profile with different omniauth authentications.

Basically a User creates Artist profiles and other users can join, so:

```
User has_many Artists

Artist has_many Users
```

However I can't figure out if the Artist model should also be a Devise generated one.

**Scenario one:**
If the Artist Model is **not** devise generated won't omniauth authentications mess up the current user authentications and cause the user to sign out?

**Scenario two:**
If the Artist Model is devise generated, can a devise model have a an association with another devise model? and How can I switch between them, (probably like facebook pages associated with users)?

**Desired result:**
Both User and Artist to have different omniauth authentications to fetch different data.
Users and Artists to be associated with one another.

It is a very specific question but I would appreciate any support.

Comment: I think easier way would be combine user and artist model to be one and the same. Have a flag attribute `is_artist` or something and differentiate between regular user and artist user.

Comment: Do they both need authentication? An different authentication?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! They both need authentication tho. Users authenticate with their personal facebook and twitter accounts, but if they also play in a band for example, they need to link their Artist profile to the Facebook and twitter of their band.
I would prefer if users didn't have to authenticate with their Artist account to post on it's behalf, but I still need to fetch stuff from twitter, facebook, etc.